# How do I open images in Java on mac?

Tags: java, image

**If I open a image in java on a PC I typ in C:/ user/ and so on.

How do I do it on a mac?**
I have tried copy paste from Info on image.

Comment: The root of the Mac file system is / (The equivalent of "c:\somefolder\image.png" is "/somefolder/image.png")

Comment: Extending @folkol comment if you have additional drives it will be mounted in `/Volumes/<drive name>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of hard coding the path, you can use system properties. System.getProperty("user.home") will return home directory on your Windows or Mac. Use System.getProperty("path.separator") instead of forward or backward slashes.

For more properties see JavaDoc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
new File("/Users/al/some-picture.jpg")
```